# Is it self-plagiarism if I am up-front about similarities?

Tags: publications, plagiarism

I am writing a paper which expounds on a portion of a previous paper that I got published.

If I did not even mention the previous paper in my new one, I'm fairly certain this would be seen as trying to pass off old work as new (unethical).

However, in the introduction of the new paper, the beginning of the relevant section, and throughout the relevant section, I am very up-front about the similarities to the old paper, with many citations. Also, there is no copy/paste from the old paper.  Some phrasing may be similar in places, but only because I happened to write both papers.

Am I safe submitting the new paper to a journal?

Comment: What percentage of your paper is new? Not just new phrasing, but new ideas and insights, new research, new conclusions?

Comment: (Comment not an answer since I’m pretty sure this is a duplicate question.)  There are two main issues to consider: *plagiarism*, and the journal’s *expectation of original content*.  If you are being clear about referencing any re-used material (either verbatim or paraphrased), as you say, then you are not committing plagiarism or so-called self-plagiarism.  If when you discount that re-used material there is enough original material in the new paper to meet the journal’s standards for original content, then yes, you are fine to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are on safe ground.  Moreover, if you are merely replicating previous results for context, it might not even be necessary to repeatedly cite the original paper at each step.  You could simply cite the original paper up front, explain that you are extending it, and that some results are repeated for context and completeness.  So called "self-plagiarism" involves an attempt to "pass off" your old work as new work, so check your paper to see if this is occurring.  From what you have described, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the new paper extends the prior one, presents new data or analysis, and you cite properly, you are fine. It is best to pretend you did not write the prior work and cite accordingly, because you assume no special status even though you authored it. This would only become problematic if you attempt to pass off the same work (even if edited) as a distinct novel work.